# Calling build.doStop() in prebuild is not stopping fast enough

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to write a Jenkins plugin that can automatically abort a build if that build is triggered on a holiday (or just a given input day/s). The user can configure the days, and each job gets a checkbox that allows the user to decide if they want their job aborted on a holiday or not. Currently my plugin extends **JobProperty** and utilizes global configuration where I have a list of blacklisted dates. If today is on my list of blacklisted days, then I do not want my job to run.  The plugin "works" but with a few annoying caveats.

My main issue is that I can only FAIL the build if it happens to be triggered on a day that's one of my blacklisted days.  This is a problem for me because there's no actual error. The job is operating as it should be and I don't want to receive emails full of errors just because the job was halted on a day I didn't want it to run (e.g: a holiday)

When my plugin decides to abort a build, I want to be able to end the job with an "Aborted" status.  (In fact - I'd like to be able to control the status and leave it as a potential parameter.)

Below is my prebuild() code.

```
@Override
public boolean prebuild(AbstractBuild build, BuildListener listener) {
    boolean stopped = false;
    if(checkIfClosed) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        listener.getLogger().println("Checking the date for " + DateFormats.yyyyMMdd.print(today));
        if (getDescriptor().getUseCalculatedDateChecker()) {
            if (!NyseHolidayChecker.isMarketOpen(today)) {
                listener.getLogger().println("Closed (From auto calculation)!");
                stopped = true;
            }
        }
        if (getDescriptor().getListOfClosedDates() != null && !getDescriptor().getListOfClosedDates().isEmpty()) {
            if (getDescriptor().getListOfClosedDates().contains(DateFormats.yyyyMMdd.print(today))) {
                listener.getLogger().println("Closed. Date is in the Closed Date List. " +
                        "If this is wrong check global configuration.");
                stopped = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(stopped) {
        try {
            if(build.doStop() == null) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            listener.getLogger().println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            listener.getLogger().println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        //throw new RuntimeException("This job has been told not to run when marked as Closed!");
        //throw new AbortException("This job has been told not to run when marked as Closed!");
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've tried several different ways to get the job to abort immediately and not have the build marked as failed.

1. The [doc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/JobProperty.html#prebuild(hudson.model.AbstractBuild,%20hudson.model.BuildListener)) tells me that I should throw an AbortException but that does not appear to be supported by the function I'm overriding.
2. I also tried to call doStop() but then my first build step (out of 2) still runs at least a little. This isn't desirable because I will never know what state my job will be in when it will be aborted (it could have already sshed somewhere and killed a process...or made something live etc)

What am I missing? I feel like I'm hacking around to get what I need.  I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction on how to best do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging further into Jenkins code showed the Build.doRun() method will execute the build steps in a do while loop which was allowing for a small bit of the build step to get through. The AbortException which Jenkins documentation recommends will also mark a build as failure (undesirable). The only means I found to cancel a job and have it properly mark as just aborted was to throw an InterruptedException. The JobProperties prebuild() function does not allow for any throws (other than Runtime which will mark as failure).

The plugin now extends [BuildWrapper](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/tasks/BuildWrapper.html). This has both a setUp and preCheckout method that will run prior to build steps executing. These two methods can also throw InterruptedExceptions. Now if my checks pass and the date is blacklisted an InterruptedException is thrown from the interruptOnHoliday(...) method. The BuildWrapper also utilizes a [BuildWrapperDescriptor](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/tasks/BuildWrapperDescriptor.html) which will place a checkbox in the job configuration based on the name provided in the overridden getDisplayName() function (Acts sort of as a jetty optionalBlock). With this box checked the setUp function can get called, otherwise it will not. This effectively makes the holiday check plugin optional (desired).

To give help to a user on what the Plugin does, include a help.html file in the resources for the plugin, this will allow the programmer to explain to the user how and why to use the Plugin. The BuildWrapperDescriptor class will programmatically know how to use that file.

Hope this helps everyone. Below is the new way to kill :

```
@Override
public void preCheckout(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    interruptOnHoliday(build, listener);
}

/**
 * Run a check against todays date and dates from the {@link NyseHolidayChecker}
 * which is an automatic calculator for New York Stock Exchange holidays and also a check against the manually
 * created user date list. If either one is not checked to be used, then they will be ignored.
 *
 * @param build {@link hudson.model.AbstractBuild} that we are on, will kill the executor
 * @param listener  {@link hudson.model.BuildListener} that we will log to
 *
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
private void interruptOnHoliday(AbstractBuild build, BuildListener listener) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean stopped = false;
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    listener.getLogger().println("Checking the date for " + DateFormats.yyyyMMdd.print(today));
    //if the NYSE calculator is checked then let's use it
    if (getDescriptor().getUseNyseCalculatedDateChecker()) {
        if (!NyseHolidayChecker.isMarketOpen(today)) {
            listener.getLogger().println("The NYSE is not Open today (From auto calculation)" +
                    " and this job is marked to abort. Stopping the build!");
            stopped = true;
        }
    }
    //If we have inserted manual dates into the list we want to check them
    if (getDescriptor().getListOfClosedDates() != null && !getDescriptor().getListOfClosedDates().isEmpty()) {
        if (getDescriptor().getListOfClosedDates().contains(DateFormats.yyyyMMdd.print(today))) {
            listener.getLogger().println("This date is blacklisted, and this job is marked to abort. " +
                    "Stopping the job! If this date should not be on the list check Jenkins Settings.");
            stopped = true;
        }
    }
    //if we should stop the job then we call doStop() on the build and we also throw an InterruptedException
    //The InterruptedException is the only way to abort a build without it failing.
    if (stopped) {
        try {
            build.doStop();
            throw new InterruptedException(DateFormats.yyyyMMdd.print(today) + " is a blacklisted date.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            listener.getLogger().println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            listener.getLogger().println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

@Override
public BuildWrapper.Environment setUp(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    interruptOnHoliday(build, listener);
    return new CloseCheckerEnvironment();
}
```